# Can I define a macro using a macro in C?

Tags: c, macros, embedded, c-preprocessor, preprocessor

I have a set of #defines like these:

```
#define MODULE1_PINMASK 0x1
#define MODULE2_PINMASK 0x2
#define MODULE3_PINMASK 0x3
```

where the value of the pinmask depends on the second argument of:

```
#define MODULE1_PORT_PIN A,1
#define MODULE2_PORT_PIN A,2
#define MODULE3_PORT_PIN A,3
```

If at any point in future, I make a change, e.g:

```
#define MODULE1_PORT_PIN A,1 /* changes to #define MODULE1_PORT_PIN A,4 */
```

I need to also change the pinmask:

```
#define MODULE1_PINMASK 0x1 /* then becomes #define MODULE1_PINMASK 0x4 */
```

I'm trying to automate the process by not having to manually change the pinmask. So far I've got these macros to extract the second argument of MODULEX_PORT_PIN (I don't care about the first argument in this case):

```
#define GET_SECOND(X, Y) Y
#define GET_PIN(PORT_PIN) GET_SECOND(PORT_PIN)
```

If i use them in functions, I get the correct result, for instance:

```
uint8_t pinmask=0x0;

switch (GET_PIN(MODULE2_PORT_PIN))
{
    case 1:
        pinmask = 0x1;
        break;
    case 2:
        pinmask = 0x2;
        break;
    case 3:
        pinmask = 0x3;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

printf ("%#x", pinmask); /* prints "0x2" */
```

but I want to keep the pinmasks as #defines. Is there a way to implement a `#define GET_PINMASK` macro which uses the switch case to define the pinmask? I'm aiming for something like:

```
#define MODULE1_PINMASK ASSIGN_PINMASK(GET_PIN(MODULE1_PORT_PIN))
```

which in this case would define MODULE1_PINMASK as 0x1.

EDIT: The second argument in `#define MODULE1_PORT_PIN A,1` is an uint8_t and not a hex value and so I can't pass it directly.

Comment: In `#define MODULE1_PORT_PIN A,1`, is the `1` (or whatever is there) to be interpreted as hexadecimal? So if there was a `#define MODULE23_PORT_PIN A,23`, then there should be `#define MODULE23_PINMASK 0x23`. Is that correct?

Comment: @internetAusie, the value is actually an uint8 and so I can't pass it directly.  Sorry for not clarifying, I've edited my post.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you are aware of the following facts: 1. A macro (with () as well as without) is just subject of text replacement in the macro preprocessor. 2. 0x1 = 1, 0x2 = 2, ..., 0x9 = 9. Whereever decimals are accepted, hexadecimals are as well (and vice versa).

Comment: @Scheff, 1. I am aware a macro is simply a text replacement but I thought I should ask in case there's any way to achieve it. 2. I've given these hex values to simplify the question. In reality, the int value represents a binary shift of X bits. So for example in `#define MODULE2_PORT_PIN A,2`, the hex value I'm after is 0x4 (0b1<< 2 or 0b100)

Comment: That's something what matters. I would prefer `enum` in this case: e.g. `enum { PIN1 = 1, PIN2 = 2, PIN3 = 4, MASK1 = 1 << PIN1, MASK2 = 1 << PIN2, MASK3 = 1 << PIN3 };` `enum`s are compile-time resolved (no overhead for computation at runtime) and no necessity for "macro magic". ...and, of course, you may use enumerators for `case` labels of the `switch` statement.

Comment: We need more information about the contexts where the MASK macros will be used.  Specifically: (1) Will they ever be used in `#if` expressions? (2) Will they ever be used in contexts where they _must_ expand to a numeric literal, rather than a general (integer constant) expression?

Comment: Also, your statement "the second argument in `*_PIN` is a uint8_t and not a hex value" doesn't make any sense.  You have only shown second arguments that are small, unsuffixed, decimal literals; these have type `int` in the compiler proper (more precisely "translation phase 7"), and no type at all within the preprocessor (in the one place where the preprocessor does arithmetic, it does it in `intmax_t` no matter what).  As is, I don't see a problem, but if the second argument was ever a _variable_, that would immediately mean that what you want could not be done; does that happen?

Comment: Also, literals have types in themselves; and the type of `1` is `int`, not `uint8_t`.  You seem to be describing its type in terms of where you're putting that literal in some context, but this being a macro... that has no effect on other contexts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you may be overthinking the problem.  If the second field of each `MODULEn_PORT_PIN`  define is always an [integer constant expression](https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2010/12/27/constant-expressions/), then this should work:

```
#define MODULE1_PORT_PIN A,1
#define MODULE2_PORT_PIN A,2
#define MODULE3_PORT_PIN A,3

#define GET_SECOND(X, Y) (Y)
#define PIN_TO_MASK(PIN) (1ul << GET_SECOND(PIN))

#define MODULE1_PINMASK PIN_TO_MASK(MODULE1_PORT_PIN)
#define MODULE2_PINMASK PIN_TO_MASK(MODULE2_PORT_PIN)
#define MODULE3_PINMASK PIN_TO_MASK(MODULE3_PORT_PIN)
```

It is not clear from your question whether the second field can be something other than an integer constant expression.  If the second field ever involves an `enum` constant, then the `MODULEn_PINMASK` macros can still be used in any context except for `#if` expressions.  If it ever involves a *variable*, then they can only be used inside the body of a function.  (Since this is C and not C++, that's true even if the variable is `const`.)

There is no way to avoid having to write each `#define` individually.  If that is a problem, you should be thinking about writing a program that generates the list of `#define`s.  Generating source code from a [DSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) of your own invention, at build time, is an under-valued technique.

Comment: Thanks, @zwol that works. I was making my life difficult and ignored the simplest approach...

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [x-macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro)?

You start by creating an abstract `#define` for the list of entries:

```
#define CREATE_LIST() \
    ENTRY(1, A, 0x1) \
    ENTRY(2, A, 0x2) \
    ENTRY(3, A, 0x3)
```

And then invoke the list for different definitions of `ENTRY`:

```
// Get the number of entries. Creates something like:
//   const uint8_t PIN_COUNT = 0 + 1 + 1 + 1;
#define ENTRY(number, x, y) + 1
const uint8_t PIN_COUNT = \
    CREATE_LIST()
;
#undef ENTRY

// Array of first parameters
#define ENTRY(number, x, y) #x ,
const char * Pin_names[PIN_COUNT] =
{
    CREATE_LIST()
};
#undef ENTRY

// Array of second parameters
#define ENTRY(number, x, y) y,
const uint8_t Pin_masks[PIN_COUNT] =
{
    CREATE_LIST()
};
#undef ENTRY

// Array of module names
#define ENTRY(number, x, y) STRINGIFY(MODULE ## number) ,
const char * Module_names[PIN_COUNT] =
{
    CREATE_LIST()
};
#undef ENTRY
```

The preprocessor will expand this to something like:

```
const uint8_t PIN_COUNT =
    + 1 + 1 + 1
;

const char * Pin_names[PIN_COUNT] =
{
    "A" , "A" , "A" ,
};

const uint8_t Pin_masks[PIN_COUNT] =
{
    0x1, 0x2, 0x3,
};

const char * Module_names[PIN_COUNT] =
{
    "MODULE1", "MODULE2", "MODULE3"
};
```

The possibilities are endless. It's less readable, but perhaps slightly more maintainable.

Comment: X macros should only be used as the very last resort. In this case, the OP needs to do very basic stuff - pin digital I/O, which could be solved in much simpler ways. It is not like they are the first person on earth who writes a microcontroller program with digital I/O. One define per port and one per pin mask should be sufficient for all such programs.

Comment: It's just a suggestion, nothing more, the simplest way is already answered with the accepted answer. If you need more metadata ("named enums" are the usual example), x-macros become interesting, hence all the strings in the example above.